# Proper Socket.io socket disconnection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So I have a node js client :

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/w';
var socket = io.connect(serverUrl);

socket.emit('call', "Watchdog is talking.", function(resp) {
    console.log("Boss said : " + resp); 
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnect called');
    process.exit();
});
```

and a node js server like this :

```
var express         = require ('express'),
    app             = express().listen(8080),
    io              = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    watchdog        = io.of('/w');

//Listener for watchdog socket namespace
    watchdog.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('call', function(msg, fn) {
            console.log("Watchdog 's saying : " + msg);
            fn("Good job son.");
            socket.disconnect();
        });
    });
```

I want the client to stop after sending the data so I call process.exit() on 'disconnect' event but this doesn't seem to be a proper way to end a socket connection since I get the "socket error Error: read ECONNRESET". How could I achieve a proper disconnection ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a custom event on server side in a wrong manner. Do something like that in server side:

```
watchdog.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('call', function(msg, fn) {
        console.log("Watchdog 's saying : " + msg);
        fn("Good job son.");
        socket.emit('disconnect_fired', {});
    });
});
```

and do this on client side:

```
socket.on('disconnect_fired', function(data){
  socket.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: socket.disconnect() disconnects the socket after approx 2 mins and not immediately.

Comment: I answered it for socket.io version < 1 and it worked properly then.